# can't finish generating ssh key

Tags: xubuntu, ssh, github

I want to generate ssh key for github.

I follow their documentation at [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

I did all steps extends last:

> xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
>   Copies the contents of the id_rsa.pub file to your clipboard

here is my tries:

```
nazar@nazar-desctop:~/.ssh$ ls -lag
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 nazar 4096 Dec 21 16:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 39 nazar 4096 Dec 21 16:17 ..
-rw-------  1 nazar 1766 Dec 21 16:28 ssh-add id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 nazar  404 Dec 21 16:28 ssh-add id_rsa.pub
nazar@nazar-desctop:~/.ssh$ xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
bash: /home/nazar/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
```

Why does this happen?

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed one instruction in step 2 (emphasis mine):

> ## Step 2: Generate a new SSH key
>
> To generate a new SSH key, enter the code below. We want the default
>   settings so **when asked to enter a file in which to save the key, just
>   press enter**.
>
> ```
> $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
> # Creates a new ssh key, using the provided email as a label
> # Generating public/private rsa key pair.
> # Enter file in which to save the key (/home/you/.ssh/id_rsa):
> $ ssh-add id_rsa
> ```

The command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C you@example.com` creates a new RSA key file with the text `you@example.com` in the comment section. When the command is invoked, you are asked to supply the file name. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in this case will use the default (`/home/you/.ssh/id_rsa`).

The command thereafter (`ssh-add id_rsa`) adds the key file to the SSH agent daemon such that you only have to enter the password once a session. (see the manual pages of `ssh-add` and `ssh-agent`).

To "recover" from this mistake, you can either remove the files `ssh-add id_rsa` and `ssh-add id_rsa.pub` and start over or rename it:

```
mv ~/.ssh/ssh-add\ id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa
mv ~/.ssh/ssh-add\ id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Or, simpler, just type "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa" instead of "ssh-add id_rsa" which points to a file that is not in your home directory!

Comment: @RobinLovelace Even simpler, just run `ssh-add` without arguments. It will prompt for the passphrase for every SSH key you have with a default file name (`id_rsa`, `id_dsa`, `id_ecdsa`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is badly written:

It says:

> We want the default settings so when asked to enter a file in which to save the key, just press enter.

But in the output is shows:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/you/.ssh/id_rsa):
$ ssh-add id_rsa
```

How that `ssh-add id_rsa` command gotten in the output I don't know. When it asks for the name of the file, just press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, as it is written in the tutorial. Ignore that `$ ssh-add id_rsa` thing in the output, that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

You have files named "`ssh-add id_rsa`" and "`ssh-add id_rsa.pub`". You did something wrong. Remove those files and retry the whole procedure.

Or just use [github-keygen](https://github.com/dolmen/github-keygen) for your SSH setup. Easy and secure. *Disclaimer: I'm the author of this tool.*